# Roughly estimation about Delaunay triangulation

Tags: geometry, computational-geometry, triangulation

In mathematics and computational geometry, a Delaunay triangulation for a given set P of discrete points in a plane is a triangulation DT(P) such that no point in P is inside the circumcircle of any triangle in DT(P) [[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delaunay_triangulation#:%7E:text=In%20mathematics%20and%20computational%20geometry,triangle%20in%20DT(P).)].

In the three-dimensional case, the above proceses convers to tetrahedration of the space. In geometry, a tetrahedron is a polyhedron composed of four triangular faces, six straight edges, and four vertex corners.

I know the Euler formula which estimates the face number with perecistion. But for employing it, It is necessary to know the number of vertices, the number of edges, and the number of sites.

I want to know is there any roughly estimate about face number of the constituent tetrahedrons via Knowing only the number of sites. Also, I want to know roughly the number of boundary faces.

I will appreciate any comments that give me a little help and forgive me for writing shortcomings.